# Using ionic refresher by clicking a button

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am working on a simple firebase image uploading page; but after upload file image doesnt update it self because of url is same. but i want it to be same. so i tried refresher to get the new image, it perfectly works but i have to pull down from top.

i want to run this function when i click a button, and upload complete.

```
       <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content
          pullMin="100"
          pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
          pullingText="Yenilemek için çekin"
          refreshingSpinner="circles">
        </ion-refresher-content>
      </ion-refresher>
<img src="{{ ppURL }}">
```

ts;

```
      doRefresh(refresher) {

    const ppRef = storage().ref(`ProfilePictures/${this.myUid}`)
    ppRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      this.ppURL = url

      refresher.complete();
    }).catch(err => {
      // Handle errors

    });
  }
```

it perfectly works when i pull down and image is updating well. but i cant run this function, in an other function(click button).

```
this.doRefresh();
```

this command gives an error. anyway you know to fix that or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the `refresher` parameter optional since your call in other locations will not be passing `refresher` object.

```
doRefresh(refresher?:any) { //"?" in typescript means the parameter is optional

    const ppRef = storage().ref(`ProfilePictures/${this.myUid}`)
    ppRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        this.ppURL = url

        refresher && refresher.complete();//make sure refresher is truthy before calling complete
   }).catch(err => {
     // Handle errors

   });
}
```

This way you will be effectively overloading the `doRefresh` function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a Refresher for that. Refresher is designed to be pulled down by user. 
But if you look at Refresher code here

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/refresher/refresher.ts

You should be able to trigger that by calling the _beginRefresh function. you can get a hold of the Refresher object using Angular's ViewChild mechanism.

Comment: How can i call that _beginRefresh ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it since it expects `refresher` object. So just write new method as shown below and fires it using your `button`.

```
 refreshImage() {
    const ppRef = storage().ref(`ProfilePictures/${this.myUid}`)
    ppRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      this.ppURL = url;      
    }).catch(err => {
      // Handle errors
    });
  }
```

**Note:** If you want you can refactor the `doRefresh()` method using above too.Then it follows `DRY`.

Comment: i tried it, but it working so quick before image upload. So image showing as blank sometimes.

Comment: I am trying to fix that problem actually